# HTML CSS Problem

Tags: html, css

please check this URL.
http://works.ebexsoft.com/destin/

There is an unexpected margin/padding in the bottom. I have used css like this:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body{margin:0; color:#232323; padding:0; background: #FDF8E4 url(images/bg.jpg) repeat-x;}
* {margin:0; padding:0}
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0:}
```

But the space is not removing. What can I do? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space at the bottom is being caused by the `<div id="body_area1">` element.

In the `.css`, you have `height: 200px;` in the `#body_area1` section, which is what's causing the "empty" space at the bottom.

Either changing `200px` to be a smaller value, or removing the `height:` line altogether should get you the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

In the style.css #body_area1 height is set to 200 .Please remove it .

Comment: Its in the style.css 927th line

Answer (score 1):

body_area1 should have a height of **150px**, not 200px.